# Python: Having issue with printing out only 1 line in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

So my code outputs the value if the keys are found inside a dictionary using a userInput.  I want to print out a message saying "Disease name does not exist" if the userInput is not found in the keys of the dictionary.  I can get it to work, however, it goes through the wholeee list and repeats "Disease does not exist" for every line of the text.txt

I can't figure out how to make it just print once. Here is my code:

```
# Complete this function to meet its specifications.
# Begin with an empty dictionary, fill it, and return it.
def disease_to_code_dictionary(  ) :
    """ Function returns a dictionary with disease names as keys and
      ICD 10 codes as values. """

    diseases = {}

    infile = open("ICD10.txt","r")
    header_row = infile.readline() # skip the header row

    for line in infile :

        cells = line.split("\t") # split by the tab character

        if len(cells) >= 2 : # only if the line had a tab
            code = cells[0]
            disease = cells[1]
            disease = disease.lower() # lowercase
            disease = disease.replace("\"","") # remove all double quotes

            diseases[disease] = code
                
    infile.close()
    
    return diseases


# Complete this function to meet its specifications.
# The program should give the code if the disease name exists
# otherwise say "Disease name does not exist.".
def query_disease_to_code() :
    """ Interactive function to query code from disease name. """
    d = disease_to_code_dictionary() # disease to code dictionary

    query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")

    while query != "q" :
        query = query.lower() # lowercase
        # complete here
        for key, value in d.items():
            if query in key:
                print(value)
            else:
                print("Disease name does not exist.")
        
        query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
         
    
query_disease_to_code()
```

Comment: Your print statement is inside your loop, it will print once per loop.

Comment: oops hold on, i need to fix my code. I didn't include the "Disase name does not exist"

Comment: I'm not sure in fact why you are looping at all, if you have one disease to check for why not just use `in` ?

Comment: its a whole list of diseases.  Cause the first function is going through a file on my desktop that has a list of codes and disease names

Comment: it needs to only check if the query matches with the keys in the dictionary, if it matches spit out the value

Comment: that' what `in` does with dicts

Comment: it's not working for me, and idk why

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found my solution:

```
d = disease_to_code_dictionary() # disease to code dictionary

    query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")

    while query != "q" :
        query = query.lower() # lowercase
        # complete here
        
        
        for key, value in d.items():
            if query == key:
             print(value)
             break

        if query != key:
            print("Disease name does not exist")

        
                
    
        query = input("Give disease name (q to quit): ")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
for key, value in d.items():
    if query in key:
        print(value)
    else:
        print("Disease name does not exist.")
```

You could do

```
diseases = {'covid':'1223','flu':'1332'}
query = input("Choose your poison")
if query in diseases:
    print(diseases[query])
else:
    print("Disease name does not exist.")
```

or if you like one-liners

```
diseases = {'covid':'1223','flu':'1332'}
query = input("Choose your poison")
print (diseases[query] if query in diseases else "Disease Name does not Exist")
```

Comment: sorry fixed it now, ps you should name your variables better! 'd' is not a good name.

Comment: The problem with it is that when you see 'd' somewhere inside a function you have to search around to find where 'd' was created and work out what it stores. Whereas it is fairly obvious that 'diseases' holds a dict of diseases from just looking at the single line.  In small functions that are never going to grow it's not too bad.

Comment: i finished my code, though but thanks for helping!

Answer (score -2):

i think this might help you i proved it with this example diseasses={'name_1':'ICD_10_2','name_2':'ICD_10_2'}

```
    while query != "q" :
    query = query.lower() # lowercase
    if query == "q":
            break
    if d.get(query)!= None:
        print(d.get(query))
    if  d.get(query)== None:
        print('Disease name does not exist.')
```

Comment: Badly indented python code is invalid python code. Please fix the indentation of your code. If you need help with formatting your code in code-blocks, see [formatting help](/help/formatting)